# Using parallel python with Instance Methods?

Tags: python, pickle, parallel-python

Given that code [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/acbcaa05e6552174ffb2) I try to call :

```
p = ProgressBar(maxval=len(img_paths))

sm = SaliencyMaskSlic()
operations = [('img_resize', img_resize), ('sal_mask', sm.transform)]
args_list = [{'h_size':258}, {'cropped':True}]

pre_pipeline = Pipeline(ops=operations, arg_list=args_list)
ch = ColorHist('RGB', [6,6,6], [2,2], center=True, pre_pipeline = pre_pipeline)

for count,img_path in enumerate(img_paths):
    s.submit(ch.transform, (img_path,))
    p.update(count)
p.finish()
```

and it raises:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-b62cf2241437> in <module>()
      9 
     10 for count,img_path in enumerate(img_paths):
---> 11     s.submit(ch.transform, (img_path,))
     12     p.update(count)
     13 p.finish()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pp-1.6.4-py2.7.egg/pp.pyc in submit(self, func, args, depfuncs, modules, callback, callbackargs, group, globals)
    458 
    459         sfunc = self.__dumpsfunc((func, ) + depfuncs, modules)
--> 460         sargs = pickle.dumps(args, self.__pickle_proto)
    461 
    462         self.__queue_lock.acquire()

PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

How should I handle such case in Python on order to use pp library. Or what are the other solutions available?

Comment: where is `s` definition?

Answer (score 1):

If want to use `pp`, but have stronger pickling -- then use `dill`.  The `dill` serializer can pickle most of python.  I'm the `dill` author, and have also extended `pp` to use `dill`.

`pp` requires serialization by extracting the source code from an object, much like the standard module `inspect` does with `inspect.getsource`.  With `dill.source.getsource`, you have a much more powerful code inspection and source retrieval.

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 13 2014, 02:29:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from dill import source
>>> def test_source(obj):
...     _obj = source._wrap(obj)
...     assert _obj(1.57) == obj(1.57)
...     src = source.getimportable(obj, alias='_f')
...     exec src in globals(), locals()
...     assert _f(1.57) == obj(1.57)
...     name = source.getname(obj)
...     assert name == obj.__name__ or src.split("=",1)[0].strip()
... 
>>> def test_ppmap(obj):
...     from pathos.pp import ParallelPythonPool
...     p = ParallelPythonPool(2)
...     x = [1,2,3]
...     assert map(obj, x) == p.map(obj, x)
... 
>>> from math import sin
>>> f = lambda x: x+1
>>> def g(x):
...   return x+2
... 
>>> for func in [g, f, abs, sin]:
...   test_source(func)
...   test_ppmap(func)
... 
>>>
```

You'll need to get the version of `pp` that comes with `pathos`, and it's probably better to use the `pathos.pp` layer on top of my extension of `pp`.

This also works with class instances, and the like -- `pathos.pp` also provides an asynchronous map (see below) as well as an iterator map (not shown).

```
>>> class B:
...   def zap(self, x): 
...     return x**2 + self.y
...   y = 1
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> 
>>> res = p.amap(b.zap, range(5))
>>> res.get()
[1, 2, 5, 10, 17]
```

**Update:** I've now build a standalone fork of `pp` that uses `dill` for better serialization, called `ppft`.  No need to install `pathos` to get it. If you don't care about having a `Pool` interface, then use `ppft`, if you want a `Pool` interface, then use `pathos.pp`.

Get the code here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that the object you try to send is unpickable. The reason it is unpickable, is that's it is a  [classic class](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#newstyle%20classic%20class). In Python 3 new-style is the default, but in Python 2 you need to inherit from object:

Try to replace `class ColorHist():`  with `class ColorHist(object):` and see if it works for you.